# Could IAsyncResult in IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest ever be null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, resharper, ihttpasynchandler

Consider the following code:

```
public class AsyncRequestHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler
{
   public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   {
     if (result == null)
     {
       ...
     }
     ...
   }
}
```

ReSharper suggests that `result` could never be `null` (by indicating that the condition is always false). However, since `IAsyncResult` is a reference type, `null` is a possible value. I came up with two possibilities:

- Some kind of metadata available that allows ReSharper to conclude that `result` could never be `null`. Looking at the `IHttpAsyncHandler` source code using ReSharper, I don't see any attributes associated with `EndProcessRequest`.
- ReSharper is aware that the `IHttpAsyncHandler` guarantees that `IAsyncResult` will never be `null`. However, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler.endprocessrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't gives any clues either way.

It seems reasonable that `IAsyncResult` won't be null since it allows us to track the progress of the asynchronous task. Can someone please provide some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IHttpAsyncHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler(v=vs.110).aspx) is an example of the old-style [Asynchronous Programming Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx).

Perhaps ReSharper is designed to recognise the pattern.

Note:

> The effect of calling the **End***OperationName* method multiple times with the same [`IAsyncResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult(v=vs.110).aspx) is not defined. Likewise, calling the **End***OperationName* method with an [`IAsyncResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult(v=vs.110).aspx) that was not returned by the related **Begin** method is also not defined.

So, you don't have to write code to deal with people not properly calling your code, following this pattern.